# Elemento:First-Child Não Funciona

Tags: html, css, less

Nesse exemplo abaixo tem um elemento `.title`. E nele estou colocando um `first-child` com `margin-top:20px;`.
Quando compilo e salvo não está funcionando. Não aplica a margem no topo no primeiro elemento desse tipo.

**LESS**

O que acontece ?

```
       .linha-infantil{
            background-color: #44A5D7;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            .faixa-amarela{
                line-height: 40px;
                color: #000;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #FFF;
                text-align: center;
                border-radius: 10px;
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            .title{
                font-size: 46px;
                color: #FFF;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: "Candara";
                &:first-child{
                    margin-top: 20px;
                }
            }

            .owl-carousel{
                .item{
                    padding: 30px;
                }
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
        <div class="linha-infantil">
            <div class="faixa-amarela">
                Linha Infantil
            </div>

            <div class="title">DIA</div>

            <div class="owl-carousel">
                <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }} </div>
                <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }} </div>
                <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }}</div>
                <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }} </div>
            </div>

            <div class="title">EQUATE</div>

            <div class="owl-carousel">
                <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }} </div>
                <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }} </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Especifiquei uma classe para o elemento.

```
.marginTop10 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

<h2 class='marginTop10'>Teste</h2>
```

Answer (score 5):

O `.title` não é o primeiro filho (que, no caso, é o `.faixa-amarela`). Se `.faixa-amarela` sempre vai preceder `.title` (e sempre vai haver no máximo uma `.faixa-amarela`), use `.faixa-amarela + .title`, que funciona no IE 8+.

---

De qualquer forma, olhando o seu HTML com mais calma, você tem certeza que ele não deveria ser algo tipo

```
    <div id="linha-infantil">
        <h1>Linha Infantil</h1>

        <h2 id="linha-infantil-dia">DIA</h2>

        <ul class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }} </div>
            <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }} </div>
            <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }}</div>
            <div class="item">{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }} </div>
        </ul>

        <h2 id="linha-infantil-equate">EQUATE</h2>

        <ul class="owl-carousel">
            <li>{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }}</li>
            <li>{{ HTML::image('img/marcas/') }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Aí você pode colocar estilos genéricos nos cabeçalhos, especializar pelo `id` dos cabeçalhos que você quer especializar, e se o servidor engasgar e não estiver servindo o CSS, a página ainda fica legível, com a formatação padrão do browser.

Comment: Não entendo. Eu estou fazendo um `&:first-child` no elemento específico `.title` e não no elemento pai `.linha-infantil`. Eu já usei esse `first-of-type`. Sem sucesso também. Eu estou usando o CodeKit. Esse programa já compila o código que funcione para todos os navegadores.
`> 5%, last 5 versions, ie >= 5.5, ff >= 2, Chrome >= 4, Safari >= 3.1, Opera >= 9.5,ios >= 3.2, android >= 2.1`

Comment: Falei besteira com o `:first-of-type`: a definição de “primeiro” dele é específica pra tags, parece. Tendo dito isso, eu fiz um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m4g02eh/) ilustrativo: `:first-child` é uma propriedade que se aplica ao _filho_, e não ao pai, apesar de quem _é_ o primeiro filho depender, obviamente, do pai.

Comment: Então, no JSFiddle coloquei um `<p>Teste</p>` acima do primeiro `span` da primeira `div`. E não acatou o `background` no primeiro `span`. Apenas na segunda `div`, no primeiro `span` que acatou. E você especificou para o `span` no CSS. Então, está acontecendo a mesma coisa comigo. Vou ter que criar uma classe a parte, tipo, `.marginTop` e setar no primeiro elemento `div.title`. Mas queria realmente usar o **pseudo-element**.

Comment: `:first-child` funciona desse jeito; é intencional que ele deixe de receber o background. Eu acho que você está sofrendo porque a _estrutura_ do seu documento não é compatível com a _semântica_ do seu documento. Porque você quer usar o pseudo-element? Porque o HTML que eu botei na resposta não é melhor do seu ponto de vista?

Comment: 1 - Por que eu quero usar o pseudo-element ? - Estou usando LESS.
2 - Por que o HTML que você colocou na resposta não é melhor no meu ponto de vista ? - Exato. E além disso não funcionou e a estrutura do meu HTML está exatamente como tem que ser. Não pode ser igual a sua do JSFiddle. Mas obrigado.